Why do central banks use open market operations to manipulate interest rates instead of directly creating or destroying reserves electronically?
My understanding is Central banks traditionally (pre quantitative easing) use open market operations to influence short-term interest rates by buying or selling government securities. This affects the supply of reserves in the banking system, which in turn affects the overnight federal funds rate, or the rates that banks lend to each other. For example if the Central bank wants to stimulate the economy to reach full employment it will create reserves to purchase short term treasuries on the open market injecting liquidity in the system.Participating bank reserves will increase and this will have a ripple effect on the broader economy as it will lend out money at a lower rate, stimulating business, stock markets and broader economy. Similarly if the central bank wants to lower inflation it will sell the securities it holds taking reserves out of the system, reducing money supply. The banks will have less money to lend others, and interest rates will go off, cooling the economy.
However, it seems counterintuitive to use such a convoluted process when the central bank could simply create or destroy reserves electronically (without corresponding asset transaction). For example if the Central bank wants to stimulate the economy why does it simply not create reserves electronically and deposit it into participating banks (without purchasing Treasuries). Similarly if it wants coool the economy simply electronically erase reserves (without having to sell treasuries to take money out of the system).
What are the reasons behind this approach? Is it related to maintaining balance sheet neutrality (Zero sum. Ultimately transactions are neutral for both central and participating banks) or avoiding inflationary pressures? Or is it the reversibility of the process?

You seem to be suggesting just giving reserves to banks (or taking them away). This probably isn’t even legal- Fed is supposed to do fair market level transactions.  Unless I misinterpreted.
